# difference between char* and int* in C when used with printf

Tags: c, pointers, printf

This could be a very basic question, but I am not able to understand it. I need a clear understanding, hence am posting here.

Consider the code:

```
char *c = "hello";
int   a = 10;
int  *b = &a;
printf("%s\t%d\n", c, *b);
```

Why do I have to pass `*b` to get value to be printed but in case of strings if I just give c `printf` still prints "hello"?

Answer (score 3):

That's just what the specifiers mean:

- `%s` wants a pointer to a char, so you don't have to dereference it, `printf` will
- `%d` wants a true integer so you *do* have to dereference it

It's just what `printf` is and always was.

Answer (score 3):

Because that's how `printf` is defined.

But it makes sense; consider the following code:

```
printf("%d\n", 42);
```

What would the equivalent code be if `printf` took integers via pointer?

Strings are a special case; a string in C is a sequence of characters in memory, accessed via a pointer to its first element.  So you need to give `printf` that pointer, so that it can read the whole string.